# triggering proximity sensor when receiving phone calls

Tags: proximity-sensor

i find one thing annoying with my Android phone is that ,whenever i receive a call with the phone inside my pocket, i accidentally end up cutting(i mean ending) the call when trying to take the phone from my pocket .so i need to create an app to do this following: whenever i receive calls i need to activate the proximity sensor and turn off the screen to prevent ending of calls. is this possible practically?i found this feature in cyanogen mod phones but not with other standard android skinned phones

Comment: *i need to create an app to do this following* -- that's Off-topic here (see [help/on-topic]). You can actually tweak this line to make the question On-topic.

Answer (score 0):

There might be a module for Xposed (root) that you could try to enable. This feature is available in CynaogenMod so you could also flash CyanogenMod to your phone if there is a ROM available.